# MouseDoubleClick event is not fired when a cell is double-clicked in System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagrid, double-click

I need to handle when a cell is double-clicked in a ReadOnly DataGrid (not DataGridView unfortunately), but the MouseDoubleClick event is not being fired. How can I make the event fire?

I'm creating the DataGrid and subscribing to the event:

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("foo");
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "foo" });
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "foo" });
dataGrid1.DataSource = table;
dataGrid1.MouseDoubleClick += DataGrid1_MouseDoubleClick;
dataGrid1.ReadOnly = true;
```

The event is only if I double click on the border between cells. When I click on a cell a ReadOnly textbox appears which seems to eat the second click event:

[image]

I found [an old thread in Experts Exchange](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20454852/HitTest-on-DataGrid-DoubleClick-event.html), where they say as much:

> Well, not only is the double click event not being captured when clicking on a cell, it is not being caught by the datagrid message queue.  I inherited a datagrid and overrode the wndproc, checking to see if I could detect the double click.  It captures the click message, but no WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK message comes through.  I suspect that MS has the child cell control (see DataGridColumnStyle class and derivatives) hook the grid control and prevent the message from even continuing to the grid.  Trying to pre-hook that child or the grid could have pretty messy results, so I am avoiding that.

I don't really need the TextBox control so if there is a way to suppress the cells from "activating" or showing it, that would be a good enough solution for me as well.

*Note: I know DataGrid is obsolete, but I'm dealing with legacy code, please don't comment to tell me to use DataGridView - it doesn't help me.*

Comment: Could you handle simple click event on a cell instead of a double click?

Comment: If you don't need the grid to activate could you put a transparent control over the top to capture the mouse click?

Comment: @Equalsk Interesting idea. The control would have to be resizable along with the Grid but maybe I could achieve that with Anchoring. It would have to be over the cells only as I definitely want to be able to click on the header row - to resize the column widths, and to change the sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a mouse down occurs on a cell, the `TextBox` editing control gets the focus and receives other mouse ups and downs, so double click event of [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) will not raise.

Since your `DataGrid` is read-only, you can change [DataGridTextBoxColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridtextboxcolumn?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to not show editing control. This way double click event will raise. To do so, it's enough to override this overload of `Edit` method and do nothing:

```
public class MyDataGridTextBoxColumn : DataGridTextBoxColumn
{
    protected override void Edit(CurrencyManager source, int rowNum,
        Rectangle bounds, bool readOnly, string displayText, bool cellIsVisible)
    {
    }
}
```

**Example**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("A");
    dt.Columns.Add("B");
    dt.Rows.Add("1", "11");
    dt.Rows.Add("2", "22");
    var dg = new DataGrid();
    dg.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.Controls.Add(dg);
    dg.BringToFront();
    dg.DataSource = dt;
    var ts = new DataGridTableStyle();
    ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(new MyDataGridTextBoxColumn() { MappingName = "A" });
    ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(new MyDataGridTextBoxColumn() { MappingName = "B" });
    dg.TableStyles.Add(ts);
    dg.DoubleClick += dg_DoubleClick;
}
void dg_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("DoubleClick!");
}
```